# How to create a mountable ISO image file

Tags: iso

How can I create an ISO image file of my Ubuntu system which I CAN INSTALL later ?

I used remastersys, but it created me only a live version. When I tried the install option on the generated ISO image file it acted as a live version whilst I need to install it on an other computer.

Comment: You can install Ubiquity in your system then run remastersys. Ubiquity can install Ubuntu from the live system.

Comment: I installed it but it did not work, same problem: there is an item to select for installation, but when i choose it it acts like live version, not installation one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have a look to the application called [mondorescue](http://www.mondorescue.com/)

This is a recovery tools that will allow you to create bootable CD or DVD images that can be reused to reinstall your system even if you insert a new hard disk into it.
The software consists intot two main executable `mondoarchive` and `mondorestore`.

Options are foreseen in the tools to

- split the image into multiple files if the total size exceed the size of a CD or DVD,
- exclude some directories
- specify different destination media like network share, USB, ...

Of course, read carefully the documentation and test because some special disk layout may not be able to be archived using this tools.

During the restore of such an image, you can be prompted to enter dialog where you can alter the disk partitions layout, in case you do the restoration on a system where the disk is smaller (of course it cannot be smaller that the total used size of the orginal system !)

Comment: Thank you Benoit. May I use mondorescue to generate an ISO image for Ubuntu Server too installed within a Virtualbox? (